# Why would I have a segmentation fault when declaring a variable in a C program?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

After having a segmentation fault in a C program I am developing, I realized the error came from my declaration of a variable.

It is the first time I tried to declare a variable of  data type Ens_participants defined below:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int cardinal;
    Participant tab[NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS];
} Ens_participants;
```

And Participant is another data type I created defined below:

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    char nom[TMAX_MOT];
    char prenom[TMAX_MOT];
    char email[TMAX_MOT];
    char nationalite[TMAX_MOT];
    char langues_parles[LMAX][TMAX_MOT];
    char langues_cherches[LMAX][TMAX_MOT];
    int age;
    char sexe;
    char universite[TMAX_MOT];
    char disponible[TMAX_MOT];
} Participant;
```

With TMAX_MOT, NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS, and  LMAX being constants :

```
#define TMAX_MOT 250
#define LMAX 500

#define NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS 1000
```

This is the line that cause my segmentation fault:

```
Ens_participants les_participants;
```

Did I properly create and declare these variables? How can a single declaration cause a segmentation fault? If it helps, with the gdb debugger, I was told that the error came two lines before this declaration :

```
int ligne_valide = 1;
```

However, this is false as the program worked well with the above line. It is as soon as I tried to declare this new variable that I started having issues.

## UPDATE NO1

When I changed the value of the constant NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS to 10 instead of 1000, the program compiled perfectly.

## UPDATE NO2

I apologize for this question since, as @alk suggested, my problem lies elsewhere. I have rewritten just the types of the program and experimented. The problem is not where I thought it was. The variable definitions and declarations are not causing any issues in the new program.

Comment: Declarations are not causing segfaults.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: They do - if the compiler has a bug and segfaults :-)

Comment: Yes, but it is after commenting a single declaration (the one mentioned above), that I resolved the issue.

Comment: You likely have undefined behavior in the previous code that only rears its ugly head when you included this new declaration. The above code is not causing your problem.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @StefanN What value `NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS` does have?

Comment: @Olaf if this was the case, how would I fix it?

Comment: @StefanN This is not the case, I promise you.

Comment: @Jacajack I just edited my question

Comment: Umm, guys... I compiled those declarations and they throw segfault indeed...

Comment: @Jacajack Can you show what have you compiled and with which compiler?

Comment: By the way, I used gcc on ubuntu

Comment: @EugeneSh. There it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17376144/ I just copied those code samples and used `gcc`

Comment: @Jacajack Well, you are trying to define a large data structure on stack. This is not included in the question. And a valid cause for memory corruption. not a compiler bug.

Comment: @StefanN: Chances you discovered a compiler bug is near zero. Concentgrate on reading [ask] and finally providing the [mcve]. You have been ask multiple times! Without that a good answer is not possible and all is speculation. Notice this is not a hindsight site; crystal balls are out today, too.

Comment: UPDATE! I changed the size of NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS to 10 instead of 1000 and it compiled.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know this is not a compiler bug, I just wanted to verify if segmentation fault is actually caused by this declaration, and it is. I think Steven sorted everything out in his answer

Comment: @Jacajack It's *definition*, not declaration. There is a difference.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know, sorry for bad habits. I 'm just used to calling all those 'declarations'

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand. What is wrong with my question?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place.

Comment: @alk Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In C definitions rarely crash the program,  the  rest of the code does.

Comment: @alk - In this case, however, declaring and defining `les_participants` as an `auto` variable *does* cause a segfault (at least it does on the SLES 10 system I'm working on).  It's easily fixed by making it `static`, but it really is the definition that crashes the program.

Comment: @JohnBode: I read `changed ... to 1000 instead of 10`  instead of  `changed ... to 10 instead of 1000` :} So it might very well be one of those "*rare*" cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably just that your variable is too big for the available stack size on your platform.  The code is technically fine for C (so, not a compile-time error), but in practice the operating system does not reserve enough stack space to make this possible.

After all, your langues_parles field takes, on its own, 250 * 500 bytes of space; i.e. 125kB.  You've got three fields like that, and then some other fields, so each instance of the structure takes around 380kB.

Now, you haven't shown the value of NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS, but my guess is that 380kB * NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS is just too big.  For example, on Windows, the default stack size is only 1MB, so if NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS is bigger than 2, then the variable is too big (and that's assuming there is nothing else on the stack).

You will have to allocate your structure on the heap using malloc() or a similar function:

```
Ens_participants* les_participants = malloc(sizeof(Ens_participants));
/* ... */
free(les_participants);
```

Comment: Too much speculation. You really should ask for a MCVE before such speculation. Btw, stack size of desktop/server OS is typically some MiB.

Comment: The example struct given will be around 240Mb.

Comment: Well, `sizeof( Participant )` returns 251508, though

Comment: @Steven I am not an experienced developer, how do I integrate this into my code?

Comment: Allocating such a size on heap is not very wise as well.

Comment: @StefanN: It's kind of hard to explain if you're not used to pointers, but you could try looking for a C tutorial on "pointers" and "malloc"; something like: https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free.  Eugene has a good point; you're allocating a very, very large, inefficient structure and you'll eventually run into problems on the heap as well (if not with a 1000 participants, then 2000 or 10000, or once your allocate a bunch of memory for something else) -- but if this is a "learning" program, you might want to tackle one issue at a time and this is probably ok.

Comment: @Steven I volunteered to develop a program to be used by a non-profit organization. I need eventually to have enough space for 10 000 participants because I am simulating a real life structure.

Comment: @StefanN: It is a good idea to first learn programming before you start something like that. If you store personal information like names, addresses, bank accounds/credit card information, etc., there are legal aspects to observe, too. Would not be the first (non-profit) organisation going bankrupt due to legal issues and compensations paid for data leaks.

Comment: @StefanN Before going into programming one should know about different data structures. Data structure is not necessarily consisting of a huge single contiguous  block of memory, which is hard to allocate, but often from many distinct chunks of data linked with each other. See *linked lists* for a simplest example.

Comment: @Ben: We don't see the definition, so it still is not clear if the size is actually the problem. Also a simple array is possibly a bad container for whatever OP wants to accomplish anyway.

Comment: @Olaf I understand. It is not a serious program and does not contain any sensitive information.

Comment: @StefanN: Whatever you call "sensitive information", that might not what a lawyer would say. If you store names, this already **is** sensitive. The exact difenrtiation is subject of local laws, of course. IANAL, just caught some stuff from some friends who work in that area.

Comment: @StefanN: If you need to store that many entries, then you will definitely want to use a list or tree structure, rather than an array.  It might be worth your while to look at C++ or Java or C#, which provide these kinds of structures as predefined container types, rather than doing it the hard way in C.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2**

Here's a *very* simplistic example in C++, pretty much off the top of my head and untested, so there are undoubtedly going to be some errors.

We're going to use the standard `map`, `vector`, and `string` data types for
storing our participant data.  The `map` type is an associative data structure,
storing items indexed by an arbitrary key.  A `vector` is a linear container
like an array, except that its size is not fixed, and a `string` is, well, a string.  All of these types do their own memory management, so you don't have to worry about allocating or freeing memory as items are added or removed.

First, we need define the `Participant` type:

```
#include <string> 
#include <vector>

// By default, all members of a struct type are public.
struct Participant 
{
  std::string nom;
  std::string prenom;
  std::string email;
  std::string nationalite;
  std::vector< std::string > langues_parles;
  std::vector< std::string > langues_cherches;
  int age;
  char sexe;
  std::string universite;
  std::string disponible;

  // Generate a key for the participant based on nom and prenom.
  // The const keyword indicates that this method will not change
  // any of the non-static members of the class.
  std::string genkey() const 
  {
    return nom + ',' + prenom;
  }

  // Overload the stream input operator; we're going to assume
  // a file structure where each item is on it's own line, and where
  // the number of languages read and spoken is explicitly specified.
  // We're also going to assume the input is always well-behaved and
  // never needs validating (which is not going to be true in the real
  // world, of course
  std::istream operator>>( std::istream& s )
  {
    s >> nom;
    // repeat for prenom, email, nationalite
    int nlang;
    s >> nlang;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < nlang; i++ )
    {
      std::string lang;
      s >> lang;
      langues_parles.push_back( lang );
    }
    // repeat for langues_cherches
    // read remaining items
    return s;
  }

  // Overload the stream output operator, write in the same format
  // that we read.
  std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& s )
  {
    s << nom << std::endl;
    // repeat for prenom, email, nationalite;
    s << langues_parles.size() << std::endl;
    for ( std::vector< std::string >::iterator it = langues_parles.begin();
          it != langues_parles.end(); ++it )
      s << *it << std::endl;
    // repeat for langues_cherches
    // write remaining items
    return s; 
  }
};
```

Once the `Participants` type is defined, we can instantiate our map structure:

```
#include <map>

/**
 * I normally wouldn't use a typedef here since I don't want to
 * hide the "map-ness" of the implementation, but this will save
 * some typing later on.
 */ 
typedef std::map< std::string, Participant > Ens_participants; 
Ens_participants les_participants;
```

Once that's all done, we can read data from our input file:

```
std::ifstream s( data_file );
Participant p;

// use the overloaded stream input operator to read from our data file;
// keep reading until we hit EOF or an error.
while ( s >> p ) 
{
  // add the new participant to the map
  les_participants.insert( std::make_pair( p.genkey(),  p ) );
}
```

To find a specific entry in the map, use the `find` method:

```
std::string key = "Bode,John";

Ens_participants::iterator it = les_participants.find( key );
if ( it == les_participants.end() )
  std::cerr << "Could not find John Bode in the list of participants!" << std::endl;
else
  // process entry
```

To iterate through the map, do the following:

```
for ( Ens_participants::iterator it = les_participants.begin(); it != les_participants.end(); ++it )
{
  std::cout << "key  = " << it->first << std::endl;
  std::cout << "data = " << it->second;
}
```

The `find()`, `begin()`, and `end()` methods return *iterators*, which look and behave a lot like pointers.  The iterator returned by the `end()` function serves basically the same purpose as the `NULL` pointer value; it acts as a well-defined "there is no data here" value.

Notice that the bulk of the work is setting up the `Participant` type.  Storing and accessing the data is simply a matter of using the built-in `map` container and its methods.

I'll leave it there, since I don't know exactly what you want to do.  Again, none of that code is tested, so there are almost certainly some errors, and the style isn't the best in the world.  But, the main intent is to show you how C++ can make this kind of application much easier to write than in C.  For one thing, you don't have to specify an explicit size for anything; the strings, vectors, and the map will grow or shrink as necessary without any action on your part.  There are some even slicker tools in the standard library, but that should be enough to get you started.

Make sure you find a *good* C++ reference before starting, though.

**Edit**

Based on additional comments from the OP, I'm going to suggest that he look at a different language for implementing this system.  C is pretty much the worst language to implement a system like this, especially if you're not that experienced in programming.  Even C++ would make this task *much* easier.  It might be worth investigating what Python has to offer.

**Original**

A single instance of `Ens_participants` is almost 240 MiB wide.  Most systems that I'm familiar with will yak if you try to allocate an object that large as an `auto` (local) variable.

Before doing anything else, do some analysis and figure out how big `TMAX_MOT`, `LMAX`, and `NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS` *really* need to be.  Do you really expect to have 1000 participants?  Do you really expect any of your participant names to be 250 characters long, or for them to have email addresses that long?  Do you really expect any of your participants to be able to read or speak 50 different languages (and for any of the language names to be 250 characters long)?  And so on.

If that analysis shows that yes, your arrays really need to be that big, then there are several ways to get around this problem, in increasing order of difficulty, and all with significant disadvantages:

1. Add the `static` keyword to the declaration of `les_participants`:

   ```
   static Ens_participants les_participants;
   ```

   This will set aside storage from somewhere other than the runtime stack (typically from within the program image, meaning your executable may get a little bigger).  The disadvantage of this is that only a single instance of `les_participants` is ever created, and it's created as soon as the program starts; you're not creating a *new* instance of the variable every time you enter the function declaring it.  If you only ever intend to have a single instance of it, though, this is probably the easiest way to go.

   If you need to pass it to any function, you will *have* to pass a pointer to it whether the called function needs to modify the contents of it or not.

   ```
   void dump( Ens_participants *lp )
   {
     for ( size_t i = 0; i cardinal; i++ )
     {
       printf( "Participant %zu: nom %s, prenom %s\n", i, lp-tab[i].nom, lp->tab[i].prenom);
       // print remaining fields
     }
   }

   int main( void )
   {
     static Ens_participants les_participants;
     ...
     dump( &les_participants );
     ...
   }
   ```

   Allocate `les_participants` dynamically using `malloc` or `calloc`.  Such a large request isn't guaranteed to succeed, though, especially if your heap is badly fragmented:

   ```
   int main( void )
   {
     /**
      * calloc initializes the allocated memory to all 0s, which is
      * useful since you are going to be storing a lot of 0-terminated
      * strings
      */
     Ens_participants *les_participants = calloc( NB_MAX_PARTICIPANTS, sizeof *les_participants );
     if ( les_participants )
     {
       /**
        * use the -> operator to access members of les_participants, like so:
        */
       les_participants->cardinal = some_value;
       les_participants->tab[i].age = 24;
       ...
       /**
        * Make sure to release the memory when you are done
        */
       free( les_participants );
     }
   }
   ```

   Declare the `tab` element of `Ens_participants` as an array of *pointers* to `Participant`, and dynamically allocate each instance of `Participant` as necessary:

   ```
   typedef struct 
   {
     int cardinal;
     Participant *tab[NB_MAX_ENTRIES];
   } Ens_participants;

   /**
    * This particular implementation assumes that participant data
    * is manually entered from standard input
    */
   Participant *newParticipant( void )
   {
     /**
      * Dynamically allocate a single instance of a Participant,
      * calloc initializes all elements to 0
      */
     Participant *p = calloc( 1, sizeof *p );
     if ( p )
     {
       printf( "nom: " );
       fgets( p->nom, sizeof p->nom, stdin );
       printf( "prenom: " );
       fgets( p->prenom, sizeof p->prenom, stdin );
       ...
     }
     return p;
   }

   int main( void )
   {
     Ens_participants les_participants = {0}; // make sure everything is initialized to 0 or NULL.

     printf( "Add participant [y/n]: " );
     while ( tolower( getchar() ) == 'y' && les_participants.cardinal < NB_MAX_ENTRIES )
     {
       les_participants.tab[les_participants.cardinal++] = newParticipant();
       printf( "Add another participant [y/n] " );
     }
   ```

   When you're done, you'll need to clean up after yourself:

   ```
   while ( les_participants.cardinal )
     free( les_participants.tab[--les_participants.cardinal] );
   ```

   You've traded the iffiness of the single large memory allocation for managing a bunch of smaller memory allocations.  The code is a bit more complex now, with more points of failure.

   Implement the `tab` element of `Ens_participants` as a list or tree, rather than an array.  This is a *lot* more work, and you may not be up for it (even a simple example would make this already-too-big answer unreadably huge).  Like the previous suggestion, you're making a bunch of smaller memory allocation requests rather than a single very large allocation request, with a bonus that you can order your entries as they're being inserted.  Extra bonus, you're not limited to a fixed number of entries (as in the previous suggestion).  This significantly increases the amount and complexity of the code you have to write, however.

Comment: Seeing as how this is getting complicated in C. How would you suggest I do it in C++? I need to store information of 1000 participants read from a file (email, name, languages spoken, etc.) and then filter through this information. Or should I learn Python from scratch?

Comment: @StefanN: See my edit.  Don't take this as an example of *good* C++ code (I'm more hack than hacker), but it should at least steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @StefanN: And in the cold light of day I see a few immediate issues; `s >> universite` won't work for names like "Texas State University"; only "Texas" will be saved to `universite`.  So you'll have to use something different for any strings that need to contain whitespace.